# No OutOfMemoryError, but cannot load image

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a strange (and frustrating) problem in my game.

The game itself is drawing in canvas, so I'm not using layouts and other native elements. Just one root layout for canvas. I have implemented AdMob and Analytics, but it's disabled (and not allocating) for testing.

After few levels I can't load some images. The LogCat just output `imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> *number of bytes*`, but no `OutOfMemoryError`.

I tried the Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT), but with no luck. The Retained Size after first level is (at max) 10.6 MB, and one level before it stops loading images is 10.7 MB (sometime less). This situation is the same (with different values) in emulator and also in real device.
Comparison of HPROF files taken on first level and last shows very little differencies (~2kB).

Same thing in DDMS heap. When things are going to fail, I have 70.30% of used memory. Also the garbage collector shows 27% free memory. Here is output in LogCat:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 193K, 42% free 6680K/11363K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(16011): GC_CONCURRENT freed 118K, 27% free 8396K/11363K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/skia(16011): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 143360
D/skia(16011): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 1155072
D/skia(16011): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 450560
D/skia(16011): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 143360
D/skia(16011): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 36864
D/skia(16011): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 40960
```

Another strange thing is that when I output `Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()` to console, after level it's always bigger (~0.7 MB increment). But MAT is not showing any growth in memory usage. This behaviour is occuring on 2 different real devices.

I think I have a quite big memory leak. But MAT is not showing any growth and OutOfMemoryError is not throwing.
So I don't know where to look on leaks/allocations etc.

**EDIT:**

Maybe I'm not using MAT properly, so if someone is interested, here are 2 hprof files. One is at first run and second one level before memory problem.

[link to zip file](http://www.filedropper.com/hproffiles)

Just for the security

> MD5 8f4ef3eeb28c1d129ac0c0ef01cc8583 
>   SHA-1 0afc1cc06527225ad3029ef2bb4ebc5fe12d02a2

Answer (score 0):

Android resizes images from drawable folder to work on different resolutions. And this resize can mess up your image loading.

To fix this, I suggest that you copy the images (that are causing the issue) to all folders drawable-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and run your test. It should work.

Side Effects

**Negative** : Bigger APK size

**Positive** : Images load faster, with very less memory usage. Run the above DDMS heap thingy again, you will notice a significant drop in memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for answer! All game graphics are in assets folder. Only 6 bigger images are in drawable folders. I'm supporting mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi so I think that system is not resizing them.

Comment: I fail to understand your question.